# Trying to figure out what the error means in this line of code I have written.

Tags: c++

I'm very new to C++ so this might be an easy question that has an obvious answer. Yet, as it is obvious, I can't seem to figure it out myself. NOTE: This is my first time asking a question here. So please forgive me if I don't format this well.

```
#include <iostream> 


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int withdraw, total; 

    cont<<"Please enter amount you wish to withdraw: ";
    cin>>withdraw;


    total = 500 > 0;
    cont<<"\nYou can't withdraw "<<total;



    return 0;

}
```

I keep getting error message:
 In function 'int main()':
10:2: error: 'cont' was not declared in this scope

I don't really understand what that error is trying to tell me. Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: It's `cout` not `cont`. You do also understand `int total = 500 > 0` will give you 1 for true and 0 for false because `<` is a relational operator that returns a boolean

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I did not understand. No. Professor just made us do this question out of the book to get hands on for the first week of school. I'm doing my best to understand your answer and the answers of the other commentators. Thanks for your clarification

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to run your code on Linux using g++ compiler. After I replace "cont" with "cout", the code runs as expected.

I believe it should be your compiler problems? Are you using Visual Studio or any other IDE to compile code?

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic typographical error questions. The compiler has nothing to do with this, the OP mistype `cout`.